# How to receive metadata in rasa from front end request?

Tags: python-3.x, frontend, backend, rasa, rasa-core

I am trying to build a rasa custom channel in order to allow it to receive metadata and store it in the rasa conversations tracker. Right now tracker.events shows metadata but it is an empty dictionary only. So, this custom channel that I have created is based on a solution in the link given below:

[link](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-pass-metadata-in-post-request-and-then-extract-it/15092)

But, I am getting this error each time I try and run rasa:

```
RasaException: Failed to find input channel class for 'addons.mychannel.Chatroom'. Unknown input channel. Check your credentials configuration to make sure the mentioned channel is not misspelled. If you are creating your own channel, make sure it is a proper name of a class in a module.
```

I am attaching my custom python file images along with credentials.yml file. Please check and revert if possible guys. I have been stuck in this issue from past 2 days now.

Also, if there is any other way to extract metadata coming from front-end, then please feel free to share.

[credentials.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ylV9.png)

[mychannel.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPwR.png)

[mychannel.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxDxI.png)

Comment: That error message either means a failed import, or a failure to build the class in `from_credentials`. Did you override `from_credentials`? Where are you running the command from?

Comment: which version of rasa are you using?